# getting values from posted form containing an <ul> list

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post"
    action="../SentinelOperationsUI/SystemAuditView.aspx" class="formular">

<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Buy-In
    </legend>
    <label>
        <select id="buyIn" name="buyIn" class="validate[required]">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>New System Subscription - Third Party System Evolution - Five Year Buy-In</option>
            <option>New System Subscription - ABB System Evolution - Three Year Buy-In</option>
            <option>New System Subscription - Three Year Buy-In</option>
            <option value="SID-repeated">Plant Site Subscription - Buy-In plus Synchronization</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="SIDContainer" style="display: none;">
    <legend>
        SID (repeated)
    </legend>
    <label>
        <input type="text" class="SID" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/>
        <input type="button" value="Add" class="addSIDToList" style="display: none;" />
    </label>

    <ul class="SIDList" name="SIDList" 
        style="text-transform: uppercase; list-style: disc; "></ul>

</fieldset>

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The ul-list gets populated through jquery. Is there any smart way to read the posted values at the page that im posting to? Or do i need to post them manually using $.post? Thanks

Comment: In the form submit event create hidden input, append to the form and assign its value with the desired values of the list items.

Comment: i tried a comma-separated hidden field, guess that will have to do, thanks

Comment: Yes it would work, you can also create separate element for each list or list item - up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you populate the ul with li's that each contain an input element that contains the actual value (whether or not hidden), you can just post the page and your values should be send to the server. Of course you can do it with scriping and just add the values to some object (or read them manually from the DOM tree) and pass that object to the server through some AJAX method like $.post.

Comment: Yea, but what happens if i send some values with a normal form sumbit, and some other with jquery ajax. Do they get sent at the same time (assuming that its the same button etc)?

Comment: No, that will produce two separate post actions which you can handle at the server. If in both cases the form and it's values stay intact...the post will be the same both times but it will still be two separate actions.